# opencv imencode() buffer exception

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using these codes for encode Mat image to .jpg format. It is working with small images, but when I put a large image, project give exception

> Unhandled exception at 0x76377fb2 (ucrtbase.dll) in
>   ImageRecognition.exe: 0xC0000409: 0xc0000409.

I am using opencv2.4.12 in Visual Studio 2015 and my OS is Windows 10 here is my code block.

```
cv::threshold(image, image, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY + cv::THRESH_OTSU);
std::vector<uchar> buf;
imencode(".jpg", image, buf);
```

Comment: Make sure that `image` is either `8U` or `16U` with either 1 or 3 channels. Otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some opportunities to solve this problem :

try to allocate buffer before call `std::vector<uchar> buf(50000);`
I used this solution it is worked for me. I will upgrade my opencv version to 3.2 as soon as possible

good idea update to opencv 3.2

Answer (score 2):

try reserve memory before call imencode() :

```
std::vector<uchar> buffer;
#define MB 1024*1024
buffer.resize(200* MB);
cv::imencode(".png", image, buffer);
```

Comment: Thnaks, you solved my day: for me the problem came out in destroying the vector<uchar> elsewhere and the resize solved it!