# Why does the stdout of a PNG image get flushed halfway the image sometimes in printf?

Tags: c++, node.js, png, stdout

I am trying to send a PNG file from C++ over stdout to Nodejs. However, when I send it, it seems to get cut halfway sometimes when I read it in NodeJS, while I only flush after I sent the whole PNG in C++. What causes this behaviour?

My code to send the image:

```
void SendImage(Mat image)
{   //from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637438/opencv-imencode-buffer-exception
    std::vector<uchar> buffer;
    #define MB image_size.width*image_size.height
    buffer.resize(200 * MB);
    cv::imencode(".png", image, buffer);

    printf("image ");
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);

    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Then, I receive it in Nodejs and just test what I receive:

```
this.puckTracker.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log("DATA");
  var str = data.toString();
  console.log(str);
  //first check if its an image being sent. C++ prints "image 'imageData'". So try to see if the first characters are 'image'.
  const possibleImage = str.slice(0, 5);
  console.log("POSSIBLEIMAGE: " + possibleImage);
}
```

I have tried the following commands in C++ to try and remove automatic flushes:

```
    //disable sync between libraries. This makes the stdout much faster, but you must either use cout or printf, no mixes. Since printf is faster, use printf everywhere.
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    //make sure C++ ONLY flushes when I say so, so no data gets broken in half.
    std::setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
```

When I run the C++ program with a visible terminal, it seems to be alright. 
What I expect the NodeJS console to print is:

```
DATA
image ëPNG

IHDR ... etc, all the image data.
POSSIBLEIMAGE: image
```

and this for every image I send.

Instead I get:

```
DATA
image �PNG

IHDT ...
POSSIBLEIMAGE: image
DATA
-m5VciVWjՖҬvXjvXm9kV[d嬭v
POSSIBLEIMAGE: -m5V
DATA
image �PNG
etc.
```

It seems to cut each image once as far as I can tell.
Here is a pastebin in case someone needs the full log. (Printing some additional stuff, but that shouldn't matter.) https://pastebin.com/VJEbm6V5

Comment: Why are you trying to print binary data on the first place? Is this some sort of XY problem?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: Just because the C++ program flushes once does not mean that your nodejs will be able to read it all in one go. Switch to a proper framing approach (ie one that tells you upfront how many bytes will follow)

Comment: Unrelated: don't use printf to print your image byte-by-byte. Just use the `fwrite` or `write` system call.

Comment: @VTT, I have a tracking algorithm in C++. Just for setting up the correct threshold, etc, I temporarily wish to stream the image to the browser, and after that only print the locations of the tracked objects to display in Unity.

Comment: None of that seem to require printing binary data at any step.

Comment: @Botje, thanks for the fwrite/write tip, was searching for something like that. However the buffer outputted by imencode is a vector<uchar>, and most methods I found only use char*. At this point I'm wondering if it is worth it to copy it to a char* or if it's just faster to print it byte for byte.
As for your answer on the framing approach, thanks for the hint. I will do some research on it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: @VTT, do you have a suggestion for an alternative approach? I'm just trying things I thought would work. I would love to hear alternatives.

Comment: @AmberElferink just pass `(char *) buffer.data()` to `(f)write`.

Comment: Drop the `buffer.resize()`, the buffer will be resized as needed by `cv::imencode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have fixed it and it works now. I'm placing my code here**, in case someone in the feature needs it.

**Sending side C++**
To be able to concatenate my buffer and parse it correctly, I have added "stArt" and "eNd" around the message I send. Example: stArtimage‰PNG..IHDR..binary data..eNd.
You can probably also do this by just using the default start and stop of the PNG itself or even only the start and take everything before the next start. However, I need to send custom data as well. The C++ code is now:

```
void SendImage(Mat image)
{
    std::vector<uchar> buffer;
    cv::imencode(".png", image, buffer);

    //StArt (that caps) is the word to split the data chunks on in nodejs.
    cout << "stArtimage";
    fwrite(buffer.data(), 1, buffer.size(), stdout);
    cout << "eNd";
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Very important: add this at the start of your program, otherwise the image becomes unreadable:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//sets the stdout to binary. If this is not done, it replaces \n by \r\n, which gives issues when sending PNG images.
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), O_BINARY);
```

**Receiving side NodeJS**
When new data comes in, I concatenate with the previous unused data. If I can find both a stArt and an eNd, the data is complete and I use the piece in between. I then store all the bytes after eNd, so I can use them for the next time I get data. In my code this is placed in a class, so if it doesn't compile, do that :). I also use SocketIO to send data from NodeJS to the browser, so that is the eventdispatcher.emit you are seeing.

```
this.puckTracker.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    try {
    this.bufferArray.push(data);
    var buff = Buffer.concat(this.bufferArray);

    //data is sent in like: concat ["stArt"][5 letters of dataType][data itself]["eNd"]
    // dataTypes: "PData" = puck data, "image" = png image, "Track" = tracking is running
    // example image: stArtimage*binaryPNGdata*eNd
    // example:       stArtPData[]eNdStArtPData[{"ID": "0", "pos": [881.023071, 448.251221]}]eNd
    var startBuf = buff.indexOf("stArt");
    var endBuf = buff.indexOf("eNd");
    if (startBuf != -1 && endBuf != -1) {
        var dataType = buff.subarray(startBuf + 5, startBuf + 10).toString(); //extract the five letters datatype directly behind stArt.
        var realData = buff.subarray(startBuf + 10, endBuf); //extract the data behind the datatype, before the end of data.

        switch (dataType) {
            //sending custom JSON data
                //sending the PNG image.
            case "image":
                this.eventDispatcher.emit('PNG', realData);
                this.refreshBuffer(endBuf, buff);
                break;
            case "customData": //do something with your custom realData
                this.refreshBuffer(endBuf, buff);
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        this.bufferArray.length = 0; //empty the array
        this.bufferArray.push(buff); //buff contains the full concatenated buffer of the previous bufferArray, it therefore saves all previous unused data in index 0.
    }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.error(data.toString());
    }
});

    refreshBuffer(endBuf, buff) {
        //do this in all cases (but not if there is no match of dataType)
        var tail = buff.subarray(endBuf + 3); //save the unused data of the previous buffer
        this.bufferArray.length = 0; //empty the array
        this.bufferArray.push(tail); //fill the first spot of the array with the tail of the previous buffer.
    }
```

**Client side Javascript**
To just make the answer complete, to render the PNG in the browser, use the following code, and make sure you have a canvas ready in your HTML.

```
socket.on('PNG', (PNG) => {
    var blob = new Blob([PNG], { type: "image/png" });
    var img = new Image();
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


    img.onload = function (e) {
        console.log("PNG Loaded");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
        img = null;
    };

    img.onerror = img.onabort = function (error) {
        console.error("ERROR!", error);
        img = null;
    };
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

Make sure you dont use SendImage too often, or you will overflow the stdout and connection with data and it will print it out faster than the browser or server can handle it.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
    printf("%c", buffer[i]);

fflush(stdout);
```

There are no guarantees whatsoever that only the final `fflush` will send all the data, in one chunk.

You never had any, nor will have any, guarantee whatsoever that stdout will get flushed only when you explicitly want it to. Typical implementations of stdout, or its C++ equivalent  use a fixed size buffer that gets automatically flushed when its full, whether you want it or not. As each character goes out the door, it gets added to this fixed size buffer. When it's full the buffer gets flushed to the output. The only thing `fflush` does is make it explicitly, flushing out the partially-filled buffer.

Then, that's not the whole story.

When you are reading from a network connection, you also have no guarantees whatsoever that you will read everything that was written, in one chunk, even if it was flushed in one chunk. Sockets and pipes don't work this way. Anywhere in between the data can get broken up in intermediate chunks, and delivered to your reading process one chunk at a time.

```
//make sure C++ ONLY flushes when I say so, so no data gets broken in half.
std::setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
```

This does not turn off buffering, effectively making the buffering infinite. From the Linux documentation of what happens with a null buffer pointer:

> If the argument buf is NULL, only the mode is affected; a new buffer
>   will be allocated on the next read or write operation.

All this does is give you a default buffer, with the default size. Which `stdout` already has anyway.

Now, you could certainly create a custom buffer that's as big as your image, so that everything gets buffered up front. But, as I explained, that won't accomplish anything useful, whatsoever. The data will still likely be broken up in transit, and you will read it in nodejs one chunk a time.

This entire approach is completely wrong. You need to send the # of bytes separately, up front, read it first, then you know how many bytes to expect, then read the given number of bytes.

```
   printf("image ");
```

Put the number of bytes to follow, here, read it in nodejs, parse it, and then you know how many bytes to keep reading, until you get everything.

Of course, keep in mind that, for the reasons I explained above, the very first thing your nodejs code could read (unlikely, but it can happen, and a good programmer will write proper code that will correctly handle all possibilities):

```
image 123
```

with the "40" part read in the next chunk, indicating that 12340 bytes follow. Or, it could equally well read just:

```
ima
```

with the rest following.

Conclusion: you have no guarantees that whatever you read, in whatever way, will always match, exactly, the byte counts of whatever was written, no matter how it was buffered on the write end, or when it was flushed. Sockets and pipes never gave you this guarantee (there are some slight read/write semantics that are documented, for pipes, but that's irrelevant). You will need to code everything on the reading side accordingly: no matter how small or big is read, your code will need to logically parse "image ### ", one character at a time, determining when to stop when parsing the space after a digit. Parsing this gives you the byte count, then your code will need to logically read the exact number of bytes to follow. It's possible that this, and the first chunk of data, will be the first thing you read. It's possible that the first think you will read will be just the "i". You never know what's to expect. It's like playing the lottery. You don't have any guarantees, but that's how things work. No, this is not easy, to do correctly.

Comment: Using `image 12345\n` as header (similar to HTTP chunked-encoding) gives you an unambiguous parse.